# How to correctly implement Web Crypto API generateKey and exportKey?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, cryptoapi

**Hello everyone!**

I have this code:

```
async function generateKey() {
  const algoritm = { name: "AES-CBC", length: 256 };
  const exportable = true;
  const usage = ['encrypt'];
  return await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(algoritm, exportable, usage).then(key => { return key; 
  });
}
```

when I call console.log(generateKey ()); I get: `>Promise` at first load and `>Promise {<pending>}` when update browser window.

```
async function exportKey(key) {
  const format = "jwk";
  return await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(format, key).then(key => { return key; });
}
```

when I call `let key =generateKey(); console.log(exportKey (key));` I get:  `'SubtleCrypto': parameter 2 is not of type 'CryptoKey'.`

**I have two questions about**

- What is the correct way to generate a key with the given parameters?
- What is the correct way to export a generated key in JSON format?

I come read from: [SubtleCrypto MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/exportKey)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your API usage looks correct. You are getting the error `'SubtleCrypto': parameter 2 is not of type 'CryptoKey'` because `parameter 2` is of type **Promise**. To fix this issue, resolve the promise from `generateKey` before passing it to `exportKey`

```js
const main = async () => {
  const key = await generateKey()
  const exported = await exportKey(key)
  console.log(exported)
}
```

Of course, this can get even simpler if you use my library, [rubico](https://github.rubico.land)

```js
const { pipe } = require('rubico')

const main = pipe([generateKey, exportKey, console.log])
```

The two examples are equivalent.